# Convert UTF8 to UTF16 using iconv

Tags: linux, macos, unicode, command-line

When I use iconv to convert from UTF16 to UTF8 then all is fine but vice versa it does not work.
I have these files:

```
a-16.strings:    Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode c program text
a-8.strings:     UTF-8 Unicode c program text, with very long lines
```

The text look OK in editor. When I run this:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE a-8.strings > b-16.strings
```

Then I get this result:

```
b-16.strings:    data
a-16.strings:    Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode c program text
a-8.strings:     UTF-8 Unicode c program text, with very long lines
```

The `file` utility does not show expected file format and the text does not look good in editor either. Could it be that iconv does not create proper BOM? I run it on MAC command line.

Why is not the b-16 in proper UTF-16LE format? Is there another way of converting utf8 to utf16?

More elaboration is bellow.

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE a-8.strings > b-16le-BAD-fromUTF8.strings
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 a-8.strings > b-16be.strings 
$ iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-16LE b-16be.strings > b-16le-BAD-fromUTF16BE.strings

$ file *s
a-16.strings:                   Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode c program text, with very long lines
a-8.strings:                    UTF-8 Unicode c program text, with very long lines
b-16be.strings:                 Big-endian UTF-16 Unicode c program text, with very long lines
b-16le-BAD-fromUTF16BE.strings: data
b-16le-BAD-fromUTF8.strings:    data


$ od -c a-16.strings | head
0000000  377 376   /  \0   *  \0      \0  \f 001   E  \0   S  \0   K  \0

$ od -c a-8.strings | head 
0000000    /   *   *   *       Č  **   E   S   K   Y       (   J   V   O

$ od -c b-16be.strings | head
0000000  376 377  \0   /  \0   *  \0   *  \0   *  \0     001  \f  \0   E

$ od -c b-16le-BAD-fromUTF16BE.strings | head                                
0000000    /  \0   *  \0   *  \0   *  \0      \0  \f 001   E  \0   S  \0

$ od -c b-16le-BAD-fromUTF8.strings | head
0000000    /  \0   *  \0   *  \0   *  \0      \0  \f 001   E  \0   S  \0
```

It is clear the BOM is missing whenever I run conversion to UTF-16LE. 
Any help on this?

Comment: what if you used `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE a-8.strings -o b-16.strings` instead? I doubt it will fix it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: my iconv version does not support -o parameter (MacOS). As you've said, it probably would not help. Thanks for try anyway.

Comment: Your output shows `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 a-8.strings` (run on a little-endian system) generating big-endian UTF-16 with a BOM.  Can you confirm that?  Does the MacOS `iconv` command work differently than the one on Linux?  `echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t UTF-16 | od -x`

Comment: that seems to be per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2781 section 3.3 - MUST NOT prepend a BOM... for UTF-16BE/UTF-16LE

Comment: All `file(1)` does is guesswork. Very clever guesswork, but not something that you can be absolutely sure of.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`UTF-16LE` tells `iconv` to generate little-endian UTF-16 *without* a BOM (Byte Order Mark).  Apparently it assumes that since you specified `LE`, the BOM isn't necessary.

`UTF-16` tells it to generate UTF-16 text (in the local machine's byte order) *with* a BOM.

If you're on a little-endian machine, I don't see a way to tell `iconv` to generate big-endian UTF-16 with a BOM, but I might just be missing something.

I find that the `file` command doesn't recognize UTF-16 text without a BOM, and your editor might not either.  But if you run `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF_8 b-16 strings`, you should get a valid UTF-8 version of the original file.

Try running `od -c` on the files to see their actual contents.

**UPDATE :**

It looks like you're on a big-endian machine (x86 is little-endian), and you're trying to generate a little-endian UTF-16 file with a BOM.  Is that correct?  As far as I can tell, `iconv` won't do that directly.  But this should work:

```
( printf "\xff\xfe" ; iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le UTF-8-FILE ) > UTF-16-FILE
```

The behavior of the `printf` *might* depend on your locale settings; I have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

(Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution?)

Another workaround, *if* you know the endianness of the output produced by `-t utf-16`:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 UTF-8-FILE | dd conv=swab 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for help. I've edited my original question with more results based on your help. Would you know how to fix it? What if I just stick the BOM there manualy?

Comment: I'm also on Intel-based machine but running MacOS. Never-the-less the manual addition of the BOM as you've proposed works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `od -tx1z` or `od -tx1` is more useful than `od -c`

Answer (score 4):

I first convert to `UTF-16`, which will prepend a byte-order mark, if necessary [as Keith Thompson mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924403/9636). Then since `UTF-16` doesn't define endianness, we must use `file` to determine whether it's `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE`. Finally, we can convert to `UTF-16LE`.

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 UTF-8-FILE > UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE
FILE_ENCODING="$( file --brief --mime-encoding UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE )"
iconv -f "$FILE_ENCODING" -t UTF-16LE UTF-16-UNKNOWN-ENDIANNESS-FILE > UTF-16-FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an elegant solution but I found a manual way to ensure correct conversion for my problem which I believe is similar to the subject of this thread.

**The Problem:** 
I got a text datafile from a user and I was going to process it on Linux (specifically, Ubuntu) using shell script (tokenization, splitting, etc.). Let's call the file `myfile.txt`. The first indication that I got that something was amiss was that the tokenization was not working. So I was not surprised when I ran the `file` command on `myfile.txt` and got the following

```
$ file myfile.txt

myfile.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

If the file was compliant, here is what should have been the conversation:

```
$ file myfile.txt

myfile.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

**The Solution:**
To make the datafile compliant, below are the 3 manual steps that I found to work after some trial and error with other steps.

1. First convert to Big Endian at the same encoding via `vi` (or `vim`). `vi myfile.txt`. In `vi` do `:set fileencoding=UTF-16BE` then write out the file. You may have to force it with `:!wq`.
2. `vi myfile.txt` (which should now be in utf-16BE). In `vi` do `:set fileencoding=ASCII` then write out the file. Again, you may have to force the write with `!wq`.
3. Run `dos2unix` converter: `d2u myfile.txt`. If you now run `file myfile.txt` you should now see an output or something more familiar and assuring like:

   ```
   myfile.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines
   ```

That's it. That's what worked for me, and I was then able to run my processing bash shell script of `myfile.txt`. I found that I cannot skip Step 2. That is, in this case I cannot skip directly to Step 3. Hopefully you can find this info useful; hopefully someone can automate it perhaps via `sed` or the like. Cheers.